# Draw a chart after location.assign()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

i want draw a chart (with library HighChart.js ) after window.location.assign().
My problem is the chart is drew before the location.assign() so i can't see it.I see a blank page!
How i can resolve this problem?I post the code:

```js
window.location.assign("http://localhost:8009/Web#Grafici");      
      
          $('#myChart').highcharts({
          xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
          },
          series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
          }, {
            type: 'line',
            color: 'red',
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            },
            data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
          }]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="Grafici">
            <div data-theme="" data-role="header">
               <h3>Statistiche esame</h3>
            </div>
            
             <div id="myChart" style="height: 400px"></div>
                       
  </div>
```

Comment: How about set a condition which checks if #Grafici exists and then print chart ?

Comment: I try it! I insert "if( document.getElementById('myChart') != null )
      { " before " $(myChart)" but still see blank page.

Comment: I try also with $(window).load() but doesn't still work! The chart is loaded earlier than page assignment page! I don't know how resolve this

Comment: Do you think about adding the function making your chart on document.ready()? Or custom button?